# Javascript function undefined when called from input image onclick event

Tags: javascript

This seems really simple but I can't get it working...

```
    function myfunction(id) 
    {
        alert("ID: " + id);
    }
```

There is a fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/66ALW/

The error I get in Firebug is ReferenceError: myfunction is not defined
http://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/ (1)
Line 1

Comment: You have to set the "nowrap - in body" option on the jsfiddle control panel. Otherwise the code in the JavaScript pane goes into a wrapper function, so your "myfunction" ends up as a local function of that and isn't globally visible.

Comment: And that solves the problem — http://jsfiddle.net/66ALW/1/ — it's a jsfiddle config issue, not a problem with the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are defining `myfunction` in the `onLoad` event, so it isn't being populated in the global namespace.  Thus, function appears to not exist.  There are two solutions.

1. Manually put it into global namespace `window.myfunction = myfunction;`
2. Configure jsfiddle to use 'no wrap' options in the frameworks and extensions section.

Comment: Thanks to all but 1. was the answer I needed.

Answer (score 1):

You need set "No wrap in head" in jsfiddle to solve your problem: http://jsfiddle.net/66ALW/2/

```
function myfunction() 
{
    alert("Reached");
}
```

code is ok.